# Skype for Business Call Log

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, lync, skype-for-business

I am currently seeking for a REST API for Skype for Business/Lync that will allow out team access information on various calls for our company made throughout the day(since they talk to customers), such as call duration, from, to, etc. that we can display in a repeater in our web page.

We would like to store this information if possible. I have found that perhaps Unified Communications Web API(UCWA) might be the best route to take, but have found nothing relating to a call history/log.

Would this be the correct first step in trying to achieve my goal using a REST API to access our company's Skype for Business/Lync call information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to get this information through the UCWA API. (or any other Skype API atm)

One option is to use the [Call detail recording (CDR) database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398570.aspx) instead.

The other option is to use the [Skype for Business SDN SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785191(v=office.16).aspx) but it wouldbe way more involved.  I would assume the CDR would be easier for you to use as it's just database access.